# 503 Service Unavailable - What really it means?

Tags: proxy, http, web-development, squid

I developed a website and it loads in every other system but certainly not in mine ... WHen i used firebug my request show `503 Service Unavailable`

**EDIT:**

My response was,

```
Server squid/2.6.STABLE21
Date Sat, 27 Mar 2010 12:25:18 GMT
Content-Type text/html
Content-Length 1163
Expires Sat, 27 Mar 2010 12:25:18 GMT
X-Squid-Error ERR_DNS_FAIL 0
X-Cache MISS from xavy
X-Cache-Lookup MISS from xavy:3128
Via 1.0 xavy:3128 (squid/2.6.STABLE21)
Proxy-Connection close
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you have weird proxy settings. 503 usually signifies a temporary outage and has more possible causes than you can poke a stick at.

If it's just your machine that's failing, then maybe something is misconfigured in your browser, or your browser is the only one pointing to a misconfigured proxy. The squid warnings are a tell-tale. Are you running the browser on the same box as the proxy? That often causes problems due to squid's default ACLs.

Comment: @Marcelo can't get ur point... Plz explain a bit...

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell from the message what the reason is. It could be that you are behind a proxy that is unable to connect to your web site (in that case, you may see the name of a proxy application somewhere on the page); or it could be that your web site somehow can't be served to you, for whatever reason.

If it really is a *server* error and not a Proxy error, you would have to consult your server's error log files to find out the reason for the problem. You will usually find a detailed explanation of the problem there.

If you're on shared hosting, and the problem is definitely with the site, this is a case for your provider's technical support staff.

Comment: @pekka see my edit ... This was my Response headers...

Comment: @bala where is that squid running? On your computer?

Comment: @pekka it is running on my server...

Comment: @pekka i am connected via proxy

Comment: @pekka will it be router problem? Because i got the page in my laptop which i had a diff connection... My friend got the page from his home..

Comment: @bala then this is a problem with your proxy. It can't resolve the DNS address of your web site for some reason. Possibly a DNS misconfiguration in the proxy. What's the site's address?

Comment: @pekka http://www.svsbm.com/

Comment: @bala works for me. This is most likely a router/Proxy/DNS problem. As such, it doesn't belong here, you should try serverfault.com or superuser.com. I'll vote for migrating the question there.

Comment: @pekka ok i ll post it in server fault...

Comment: @bala Good luck. And on second thought, I think superuser.com is the most appropriate.

Comment: @bala: you don't need to post a new topic. Have patience, this topic will be mirgrated.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a site hosted in IIS, you should check the Windows Application event log. You'll find details why your web app is crashing.

Comment: @phillipe its hosted on a linux server....

Answer (score 0):

Are the other machines on the same LAN or are they coming in from the internet

```
X-Squid-Error ERR_DNS_FAIL 0
```

That implies that there is a DNS faliure on the part of squid. what address are you using?

Reading this im a little confused as to your setup, is the squid server yours? is it running as a forward or reverse server? Is the squid box on the same LAN as your Computer?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same (in tortoisesvn), and it was definitely after I setup the proxy to access a repos. on the web, and forgot to add exceptions for internal websites:

Add exceptions for in House servers !